# Install Pure Data (PurrData) on Slackware 14.2

Tags: software-installation, dependencies, slackware

Hello i m using Slackware with a raspberry pi model 1 B+
I want to install purr data and i have to compile it

There is a bunch of dependencies and first libasound-dev is needed

Someone can help me to find the sources files, my system have already libasound so 2
Thanks

Comment: This sounds like an incredibly hard task. Purr Data definitely is, as their source installation guide says itself, very rich in dependencies; and you're using a very niche Linux distro instead of something with a large user base where all dependencies would already be available. To top that off, you're using an old release of slackware, instead of the current one. I think you're a beginner – please don't do this to yourself unless you have a solid technical reason that is more robust than "I think slackware 14.2 is cool".

Comment: Also, an RPi Model 1B+ is a relatively slow computer, with slow and too little RAM and very slow storage. So, building software from source on it sounds like something I'd very much avoid, if I value my time and the SD card I would need to write-stress if used as swap space (SD cards cannot be written an infinite amount of times before they fail). If you go for one of the [supported Linux distro packages](https://software.opensuse.org/download/package?package=purr-data&project=home%3Aaggraef%3Apurr-data-jgu), installation would take less time than asking for the next dependency here.

Comment: The problem i have is that on raspberry pi rev 1 the default distro is unusable ( very slow ) and i like ubuntu but the distro begin with pi rev 2 and the same for debian that i know since a long time, for now except riscos, slackware is the only one with a light desktop and all the basics library and programs that i want to use

Comment: I can assure you that you will not get a faster Linux than a raspbian for a RPi 1. That small thing is just very slow. You can get light desktop environments for raspbian/debian as well – no reason to switch linux distros, and certainly no reason to go for slackware!

Comment: ok then i will think about changing the defaukt desktop of raspian

Answer (score 0):

https://packages.slackware.com/ tells me there's a `alsa-lib` package (which is usually what contains libasound). So, not knowing slackware personally, I'd assume that means the development package you need to install is called `alsa-lib-devel` or `alsa-lib-dev`.

Comment: yes i findit and nopackage for the devel i think you are right, do you know where to find arch linux arm v6, the one for pi 1

Comment: don't go for arch. Stay with raspbian. It really has no speed upsides to switch distros.